# How to listen to socketIO private message in React client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have a SocketIO instance in an Express app, that listens to a React client requests. A user can send private messages to a specific person. The server receives the private message, and should dispatch it back to both sender & recipient thanks to the io.to(socketId).emit(content) method.

How to listen to this event in React and update the message array? In order to ease the process, I have created a connectedUsers object, whose keys are mongoDB's user._id, and whose values are the unique socketID generated by socketIO. This way, I can easily address message to specific persons in the client. Once sent, the messages are stored in a MongoDB database.

Here is the back-end. The point of interest is io.on("privateMessage")

```js
const connectedUsers = {};

const socketManager = (io) => {
  io.on("identifyUser", (user) => {
    if (!([user.id] in connectedUsers)) {
      connectedUsers[user.id] = io.id;
    }
  });
  io.on("privateMessage", (data) => { 
io.to(connectedUsers[data.recipientId]).emit(data.message);
io.to(connectedUsers[data.senderId]).emit(data.message);
  });
  io.on("disconnect", () => console.log("user disconnected!"));
};
```

Here is the listening function in React. Everything works but the "privateMessage" part.

```js
async function getUser(socketId) {
  try {
    const res = await ax.get(`${serverUrl}/login`);
    const socket = io(serverUrl);
    socketId.current = socket;
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      socket.emit("identifyUser", { id: res.data._id });
      socket.on("privateMessage", (data) =>
        console.log("private message received!", data)
      );
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it doesn't seem to emit the 'privateMessage' event, there are listeners only

Comment: It's because I have a function to handle this later in the script, for more clarity, I've just uploaded the main function that listens to the server. The sending function is  const sendPrivateMessage = () =>
    socketId.current.emit("privateMessage", {
      senderId: blabla,
      recipientId: blabla,
      message: "some cool text"
      date: new Date().toISOString(),
    }); The data is well received in the backend.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 where do you call getUser function?

Comment: I also have huge problems with listening on privete in React,all other works well,i cant figure why only first private message come and render for sender and for recipient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the socket.on("privateMessage") part outside the socket.on("connect") scope.

React must load all events at the beginning.

The backend side must be responsible for the authorization.

Comment: On the server side all listeners must be inside session.

Answer (score 0):

For the client there is connection event, not connect.
Subscription to event privateMessage should be outside connection callback.

This code should work. Hope this helps

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'


async function getUser(socketId) {
      try {
        const res = await ax.get(`${serverUrl}/login`);
        const socket = io(serverUrl);
        socketId.current = socket;
        socket.on("connection", () => {
          socket.emit("identifyUser", { id: res.data._id });
        });
        socket.on("privateMessage", (data) =>
           console.log("private message received!", data)
        );
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    }
```